# Create a Name list with Input Field to add Names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to create a Javascript List with an Input Field to add new Names. My Goal is it to have a name list where i can add new ones. I want also to not add a value if the input field is empty.

My current Problem is that if i add a new name and i press the button all the already created names are added once again.

I dont know why! I am fairly new to Javascript and Jquery.

```js
var names = ['Peter', 'Thomas', 'Nick', 'James'];
var x = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    function display_array() {
        $.each(names, function(index, value) {
            $('#names').append(value + '<br />');
        });
    }
   
display_array();

    $('#insert').click(function() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        if(name != ''){
         name[x] = name;
          display_array();
        }
        x = x + 1;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="insert" type="button" value='Insert new Name'>
<div id="names"></div>
```

Comment: Your `display_array()` appends every name currently in the `names` array, so each time you call it, you'll duplicate the list.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const names = ['Peter', 'Thomas', 'Nick', 'James'];

function display_array() {
  $('#names').empty(); // Clear list before rendering
  $.each(names, function(index, value) {
    $('#names').append(value + '<br />');
  });
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  display_array();

  $('#insert').click(function() {
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value; // Get value of input field
    
    if(name != ''){
      names.push(name); // Push to names list
      display_array(); // Re-render list
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="insert" type="button" value='Insert new Name'>
<div id="names"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work for three reasons:

- You have to clear the shown namelist on `display_array()` using `$('#names').empty();`, otherwise you will add the whole list again and again
- With `var name = document.getElementById('name')` you're setting a DOM-element to `name`. But you need the value of it. For this you can use `document.getElementById('name').value;` or with jQuerys `$('#name').val();`
- They way you want to push the new name into the array will not work. Use `names.push(name)` instead

> I think [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) could be interesting for you, to get in touch with the JavaScript basics. Its really cool and for free. :)

```js
var names = ['Peter', 'Thomas', 'Nick', 'James'];

$(document).ready(function() {
    function display_array() {
        $('#names').empty();
        $.each(names, function(index, value) {
            $('#names').append(value + '<br />');
        });
    }
   
    display_array();

    $('#insert').click(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if(name != ''){
          names.push(name);
          display_array();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="insert" type="button" value='Insert new Name'>
<div id="names"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because you always **append** values

you should stick either to javascript or jquery. your code is a mixture between the two and this might puzzle you.

```
var names = ['Peter', 'Thomas', 'Nick', 'James'];
var x = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    function display_array() {
        $('#names').html(names.join('<br/>'));
    }

display_array();

    $('#insert').click(function() {
        var name = $('#name');
        if(name !== ''){
            names.push(name.val());
          display_array();
        }
    });
});
```